# Django, override many-to-many field ModelManager

Tags: python, django, model

How can i override the model manager of a many-to-many field that i have considering the following:

```
class TermsManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(TermsManager, self).all().filter(condition_here)


class Term(models.Model):
    objects = TermsManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Object(models.Model):        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    terms = models.ManyToManyField(Term, blank=True)

class Channel(Object):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

I also have a class which inherits from TermManager called ChannelTermManager.
How can i override the "terms" field of the Channel model so that
mychannel.terms calls the ChannelTermManager instead of TermManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be overriding `all()`.  If you want to change the default queryset, override `get_query_set` like so:

```
class TermsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TermsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(condition_here)
```

This is because `all()` is often omitted when other queryset functions are chained on, and you want your queryset to behave the same whether `all()` is explicitly called or not.

But even so, what you're doing is still problematic.  As explained in the [documentation for managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types), filtering the default related queryset will affect all sorts of automatic things behind the scenes (such as when dumping data to create backups/fixtures, etc.).  *You almost definitely do not want this*.  And you really don't want your related object managers doing this either (by setting `use_for_related_fields = True`), because you'll be masking what's actually stored in the database, rather than simply detecting out of date data and creating alerts or whatever to clean it up.  `use_for_related_fields` is intended for creating managers that augment the normal capabilities of the vanilla manager, not to filter.

I had a similar situation to yours however, and I handled it like so:

```
class FilteredTermsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TermsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(condition_here)

class Term(models.Model):
    allTerms = models.Manger() # Establish this as the default/automatic manager
    objects = FilteredTermsManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This way, I could do all my initial querying on the model through my filtered queryset and it looks like "regular Django", but all relational and behind the scenes queries would work on the unfiltered database.  And I could always access the true full set of objects by manually doing `Term.allTerms.all()`.

As for using different managers for different related objects, there's nothing you can really do there.  But why not just add `Channel` specific objects to your custom manager, and simply not call them from methods that operate on get `Term` querysets from `Object`?

Comment: This is pretty interesting. However, the solution doesn't cut it. My implementation of Object is to provide a EAV pattern which other apps can extend. An example would be the Channel class which extends from the Object EAV. I am filtering the data in the model manager because i need each class to define it's own type as an attribute... for example Channel class defines object_type attribute = 'channel'. Term is the EAV of categories which defines taxonomy_type.

Comment: Now what happens is, when django admin accesses channelObj.terms, the TermManager adds taxonomy_type to the query which it defines whose value is 'Category. However, i want channelObj.terms to pass through ChannelTerm because ChannelTerm defines taxonomy-type as 'channel-category' not 'category' like the TermManager. So i cannot control which manager is called by django admin to fetch queryset for any given model. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're looking for, so I can only throw out some ideas.  You may want to check out abstract model inheritance combined with the content types framework.  Or, this might be of use to you: http://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/